# How to add polygon height in QGIS or PostGIS?

Tags: qgis, postgis, 3d

Is there an easy way to set the height of polygons in QGIS or PostGIS? I am trying to visualize polygons by turning them into volumes (same shape at the base and roof, but with walls). I would then like to visualize the polygons in qgis2threejs.

Preferably the height would be just a column in the attribute table. Or a plugin that opens a window when you click on a polygon and then enter the height, which then gets transferred to PostGIS.

**Clarification:** My data currently does not contain any height information. Just normal flat PostGIS polygons.

Comment: What are the requirements for the polygons used by qgis2threejs? Does it just need a polygon with Z coordinates?

Comment: Are you aware of the "open feature form, if a single feature is identified" option? That would be an easy way to edit the attribute table and thus the height value.

Comment: @Simbamangu - I don't need a DEM or the polygons to float in the air. They should just extend from sea level up to a specific height.

Comment: @underdark - Sorry I don't know what that is about. I am already wondering if I should first try blender GIS plugin and try to visualize it there.

Comment: Please clarify: Does your data contain height and you want to visualize it? Or do you want to add height data?

Comment: @underdark - added clarification

Answer (score 3):

QGIS does not have the ability to render 3D geometries. PostGIS can store 3D geometries, but you will not have a means to visualize them with QGIS

Comment: OP is intending to _export_ them to qgis2threejs, which does allow them to be visualized in 3D in a web browser

Comment: Technically no it doesn't, you are not viewing it in QGIS. QGIS provided the means to prep the data for viewing in a different viewing software, such as exporting a KML for viewing in Google Earth. However, in this case, you will want to have an attribute that has a height value, which will be used to extrude. This process is referred to as 2.5D, as it does not have 3D geometries.

Comment: That's what I was saying - OP  doesn't need it _rendered_ in QGIS, only the correct data exported.

Comment: Then I would suggest that you state that a little more clearly in your comments. Also, the title of the question should better reflect the question that is being asked.

Answer (score 2):

1. Use DB Manager (or pgAdmin or console) to add a new column for the height value (if it does not exist yet).
2. enable "open feature form, if a single feature is identified" in QGIS options.
3. Load the layer from PostGIS in QGIS
4. Enable editing
5. Use the identify tool to click on single features. - This will open the feature form where you can enter the height value.